# How can I recreate a designer.vb file?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a windows forms application in which one of the designer.vb files is missing and has apparently been missing for years (checked all my backups). When I right-click on the vb file in Solution Explorer and select "View Designer", nothing happens. The Windows form designer generated code is still in the vb file, and the form shows up fine when the application runs. Is there any way to recreate the designer file so I can edit the form?

Comment: That is very strange indeed. You can try to "Reverse Engineer" your .exe. Install Telerik JustDecompile and add the .exe to recreate the project. Good luck

Comment: So the InitializeComponent() method is not actually gone, it just appears in the main vb file now.  It *should* be able to still edit it, just make sure that it is the first method in the file.  And sure, you can get the Designer.vb file back, but you have to do it by hand.   That requires creating the file and making it look the same as another Designer.vb file, cutting and pasting the InitializeComponent() method into it as well as the control variables.  And you have to edit the .vbproj file by hand, the same way another Designer.vb project item is used.  Risky, make sure you have a backup.

Comment: You say the designer file is missing, but the autogenerated code is still in the .vb file - I seem to recall that this was how it worked years ago - there was no separate designer file - before the addition of partial classes. So perhaps that explains part of the mystery.

Comment: Ah, that's quite possible; the form is at least four years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Form and copy the code from the `InitializeComponent` method of the old form into the same method in the *".designer.vb"* file of the new Form  (and replace the existing code in this method.). Also copy the designer generated variable declarations.

Since `InitializeComponent` creates all the controls and sets all the form properties, this copies the whole design of the old form to the new form.

You will have to copy your own code (containing Load and Click methods and so on) from the old *".vb"* file into the new *".vb"* file as well.